# can automapper create an object graph from flatted object?

Tags: automapper, valueinjecter

Is possible with Automapper to map a flat object to complex object graph?

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<PersonDto,Person>()
```

Map PersonDto.BirthCertificateFatherName to Person.BirthCertificate.FatherName

Comment: you can do this with the valueinjecter http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it can't, it does it the other way

```
Person.BirthCertificate.FatherName to  PersonDto.BirthCertificateFatherName
```

**UPDATE: [ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/) can do this:**

```
//unflattening
person.InjectFrom<UnflatLoopValueInjection>(personDto);

//flatenning
personDto.InjectFrom<FlatLoopValueInjection>(person);
```